# the first x label is missing using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, label

This is my data:

```
a3=pd.DataFrame({'OfficeName':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'],
                 'Ratio': [0.1,0.15,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.25,0.1,0.4]})
```

and this is my code to draw a bar chart:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ind = np.arange(a3.loc[:,'OfficeName'].nunique())    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35         # the width of the bars
p1 = ax.bar(ind,a3.loc[:,'Ratio'],width)
ax.set_title('Ratio of refunds to purchases')
ax.set_xticklabels(a3.loc[:,'OfficeName'],ha='center')
#ax.set_xticklabels(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'],ha='center')
ax.set_xlabel('x Group')
ax.set_ylabel('Ratio')
plt.show()
```

But, in my chart the first x label is missing:

[image]

I think this problem is not the same as [Matplotlib: Move x-axis tick labels one position to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520322/matplotlib-move-x-axis-tick-labels-one-position-to-left) because I do not even need rotate the x labels.

Could anyone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Never use `ax.set_ticklabels` without also specifying the position of the labels, i.e. `ax.set_ticks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easier way to produce your bar chart in Pandas:

```
a3.set_index('OfficeName').plot.bar(width=0.35, legend=False)
plt.xticks(rotation=0, ha='center')
```

(You still need to set the x and y axis labels and the title.)

Comment: Thanks. Could you also tell me why my problem happens?

Comment: I can only tell that for some reason `ax.bar()` adds another tick at the location -1 (call `ax.get_xticks()` to see for yourself!)) The label "a" is assigned to that tick and is off the chart.

Comment: Thanks. That really helps

Comment: @FengChen I know I'm a bit late. However, FYI: I've faced the same problem with labels on X-axis and `ax.set_xticks(...)` did the job exactly in the way I wanted to.
Please check out this question to get that clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131822/how-to-display-all-label-values-in-matplotlib