# Positioning of rotated x-axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[Data Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbD8y.png)

It appears that when I rotate my x-axis labels 45 degrees, the label is aligned from the center to the tick mark, but because each label is a different length (e.g. 'United States' vs 'India'), it makes the labels seem out of place. Is there a way to force the x-axis labels to align by the end of the label rather than the middle so they are all spaced out evenly on the x-axis?

Thanks!

Comment: `ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels, rotation = 45, ha="left")` [How can I rotate xticklabels in matplotlib so that the spacing between each xticklabel is equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152502/how-can-i-rotate-xticklabels-in-matplotlib-so-that-the-spacing-between-each-xtic) Here are the same questions as you and the answers.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!