# Fixing a Python matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a nice bar plot, but run into the following issues:

1. The horizontal grid lines are in front of the bars, even though I tried all kinds of zorder parameters of `ax.grid`. How can I get the grid to the back?
2. The tight layout is not tight. I tried `fig.tight_layout()` and `plt.tight_layout()`. How can I crop the picture automatically on all sides?
3. Is there a way to position the xTick-text, so that each "longText" is aligned with its xTick?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show_mountains(bins, fortyfive=False):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.grid(axis='y', zorder=-100, linewidth=0.2)
    fig.tight_layout()

    xTicks = list(range(len(bins)))

    if fortyfive:
        plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    ax.set_xticks(xTicks)
    ax.set_xticklabels(["longText"]*len(bins), fontsize=13)
    plt.bar(xTicks, bins, width=0.65, color="#6186f1")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.close()


domain_bins = [52, 47, 36, 15, 14, 11, 18]
show_mountains(domain_bins, True)
```

[image]

Comment: For the grid lines: `ax.set_axisbelow(True)`?  Did you experiment with the padding parameters of `plt.tight_layout()`?  About the tick label rotation, see [How can I rotate xticklabels in matplotlib so that the spacing between each xticklabel is equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152502/how-can-i-rotate-xticklabels-in-matplotlib-so-that-the-spacing-between-each-xtic/43153984)

Comment: `ax.set_axisbelow(True)` works great! `plt.tight_layout(pad=0, w_pad=0, h_pad=0)` also keeps a really tight layout. Finally: `plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha="right")` gives the perfect alignments!
I'll edit this to an answer, if you/someone else didn't start already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. as @JohanC said in a comment you can use `ax.set_axisbelow(True)` to display the gridlines behind the bars.
2. You can adjust the amount of space between the figure and the adge of the subplot using the `pad` value when calling [`tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html):

   > pad `float`, default: 1.08
   >
   > Padding between the figure edge and the edges of subplots, as a fraction of the font size.
3. You can control the alignment of the tick labels using the `horizontalalignment` or `ha` kwarg when you set the xticklabels.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show_mountains(bins, fortyfive=False):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.grid(axis='y', zorder=-100, linewidth=0.2)
    fig.tight_layout()

    xTicks = list(range(len(bins)))

    if fortyfive:
        plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    ax.set_xticks(xTicks)
    ax.set_xticklabels(["longText"]*len(bins), fontsize=13, ha='right')

    ax.set_axisbelow(True)

    plt.bar(xTicks, bins, width=0.65, color="#6186f1")
    plt.tight_layout(pad=0.1)

    plt.close()

domain_bins = [52, 47, 36, 15, 14, 11, 18]
show_mountains(domain_bins, True)
```

Produces this plot:

[image]