# How to rotate table header in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The objective is to create a table using Matplotlib from a df. Then, I would like the header (date, calories, sleep hours) to be rotated 90 degree.

Initially, I thought this can be achieved by accessing each of the label and rotate it using `label.set_rotation(90)`. However, it did not materialize as expected.

May I know how to fix this issue?

The full code is as below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import six

df = pd.DataFrame ()
df ['date'] = ['2016-04-01', '2016-04-02', '2016-04-03']
df ['calories'] = [2200, 2100, 1500]
df ['sleep hours'] = [2200, 2100, 1500]
df ['gym'] = [True, False, False]

def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=14,
                     header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                     ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
        ax.axis('off')

    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)

    mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)

    for k, cell in six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
        else:
            cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors) ])

    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/43153984/6446053
        label.set_ha("right")
        label.set_rotation(90)

    return ax

    render_mpl_table (df, header_columns=0, col_width=2.0)
    
    plt.show ()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, the table column names do not have the ability to rotate.for label in `ax.get_xticklabels():print(label);Text(0, 0, '')` Kindly refer to [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html#matplotlib.pyplot.table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the text property `rotation` in the header row like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import six

df = pd.DataFrame ()
df ['date'] = ['2016-04-01', '2016-04-02', '2016-04-03']
df ['calories'] = [2200, 2100, 1500]
df ['sleep hours'] = [2200, 2100, 1500]
df ['gym'] = [True, False, False]

def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=14,
                     header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0, header_height=2.0,
                     ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        size[1] += header_height - row_height
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
        ax.axis('off')

    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)

    mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)

    for k, cell in six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
            cell.set_text_props(rotation='vertical')
            cell.set_height(header_height)
        else:
            cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors) ])
            cell.set_height(row_height)


    return ax

render_mpl_table (df, header_columns=0, col_width=2.0, header_height=2.0)
    
plt.show ()
```

[image]

Please note that I manually adjusted the row heights in the example.